# Переход с С# на java

Tags: java, c#

Сложно ли перейти с  С# на java? Какие нюансы стоит учесть дабы не учить язык с нуля?
С чего лучше начать и какие распространенные технологии стоит выучить?

Comment: Перейти для вас не составит труда, но, на мой взгляд, главный вопрос не в этом, а в другом - а оно вам надо?

Comment: Зачем смущать человека? Язык хороший, востребованный. И вообще, чем больше знаешь, тем лучше со всех точек зрения.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, любому хорошему программисту полезно периодически осваивать какой-нибудь незнакомый язык, хотя бы ознакомительно.

Comment: осваивать языки, реализующие другие парадигмы полезно вдвойне

Comment: никто никого не смущает, просто разница между C# и Java в плане написания, мягко говоря, небольшая...<br>
Уж лучше тогда учить что-то КОНЦЕПТУАЛЬНО новое, например С++ и т.д.<br>
И как-бы в заголовке топика написано не "изучение java" а именно переход, так вот я реально не понимаю какой в этом смысл, или вы уже такой гуру С# что уже больше нечего учить?^^<br><br>
@Notafe про ознакомительно согласен

Comment: Что Вы к человеку привязались? Ну, надо ему. По работе требуется. Или душа требует. Или зарплату выше предложили. Пуст переходит куда хочет. Пусть учит, что хочет. )))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перейти не сложно, языки довольно близкие.

А как еще учить, если не с нуля? Возьмите учебник и читайте. Основы синтаксиса, принципы реализации ООП в Джаве, основные классы и их элементы. В чем именно специализироваться - это уже решайте сами. Наверное, нужно обратить особое внимание на сетевое программирование и базы данных, это, мне кажется, сейчас самое востребованное. И создание GUI тоже наверное посмотреть стоит.

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хорошо знаете C# и не понаслышке знакомы с так называемым language-agnostic programming, то имеет смысл сразу прочитать несколько книг по Java серии in-depth.

*Я в свое время зачитывался [**Effective Java.**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/)*

---

Ну а дальше все уже на ваше усмотрение, одного более-менее адекватного open-source проекта вполне должно хватить, чтобы окончательно закрепить полученные знания.

Также рекомендую внимательно изучить какие-нибудь **примеры хороших проектов**, мне например очень нравится, как написан [**Google Guice.**](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)

Answer (score 3):

Внесу свои 5 копеек в холивар Java vs. C#

Одним из принципиальных отличий C# от Java является ключевое слово virtual - необходимость ручной декларации виртуальных функций, то есть функций связываемых runtime. В Java все функции (за вычетом естественно статических) виртуальные. А в C# это надо декларировать и еще следить за тем в каком классе они перекрываются (override).

Кому как, а Java именно из-за этого мне кажется более чистой и понятной. Конечно, можно и поспорить :)

Answer (score 1):

Сложность перехода будет заключаться не в освоении языка а в изучении технологий, фреймворков. В .Net все в едином экземпляре, в мире JAVA много фреймворков, документации на русском почти нет. Заходишь в книжный магазин и видишь, что по C# .Net есть ВСЕ на русском!
а по Java только конструкции языка. = так, что я бы не советовал. Плывите по тому течению по которому уже плывете ;)